# Large text storing best practrice in django

Tags: django

I'm developing some api's for a book mobile app. So I have got some huge large text. For this api response is slow.

Is there any best way or any 3rd party solution to store large texts ?

Comment: The `TextField` can handle literally any length of symbols and the bottleneck here is the api endpoint. You need to implement a way of sending the content in separate chunks, either storing them in separate tables or do a custom division of the content on your backend (like pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Django's [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#textfield) ? It has been made for cases in which you have to store long texts.